# Where is the HTML content for my post in the API

Tags: rest-api

I've been looking at the docs and tutorials online to find out if there's a way to get to the html content of my posts. For example, [this endpoint](https://madhouseheaven.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/8687) gives me all the information related to one post, but not the actual HTML content, with its texts, links to videos. What is the endpoint for me to get to the meat of the post? I'm so befuddled. I would have thought this would be the most obvious thing in the world but I can't seem to find it!

Comment: What plugins do you use? It looks like the content of that post is empty - so maybe it's rendered some other way by your theme or some plugin...

Comment: Right... that could be. I'll try the API with a fresh install. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: If you're using a plugin such as WP Bakery or Advanced Custom Fields, they store the content outside of WordPress's actual `post_content` field. Some of these plugins have ways to expose their content through the REST API such as additional plugins that "connect" the information.

Answer (score -1):

you can use below property from return JSON object

```
post.content.rendered
```